# If I use sqlite to hold information for a dictionary app, will I be able to add information to the database with app updates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, cross-platform

I am working on a dictionary type app that will store and search information. Will I be able to add more entries or sets of information and then update the sqlite with an app update? Or is it harder than that to add information to the sqlite database.

additional information: 
I am using visual studio 2017 for mac

Comment: What makes you think you couldn't?

Comment: Because I am really new to sqlite and the nature of my project would demand that it could be updated frequently so that it can keep up with newer products as they come out. I just wanted to make sure because I'm just a new learner and don't want to invest a lot of energy in something I can't update, because I want to make sure the app's users have the most current information available. So I just wanted to check. I'm assuming your answer means that I can update the database and it will be updated when the app updates but if you could elaborate I'd really appreciate!

Comment: Depends what you mean by "update". You mean like switching from SQLite3 to SQLite4? Or do you have a fixed set of information in that db, that you ship with the App and want to update that? If users can also add information, I'd do it in two databases. A fixed one shipped with the app and a user-specific. So you can just ship another db file with updated infos without destroying the users' data. The only point would be changes to the db schema. You'd need some precautions to migrate user data from old schemas to the latest. But all of this is definitely possible.

Comment: I see, thank you for taking the time to explain all the different factors to it. That really clears up a lot of my questions and I really do appreciate it!